PHP Variable contains extra information after SQL Query Execution
I have some weird behavior happening with a parameter passed by reference to a SQL Server Stored Procedure.
I have a variable ($FormType2) in a parameter array passed to the Stored Procedure. When the Stored Procedure is executed and I output the variable, it contains 8000 characters from a different PHP file.
The PHP file in question is included at the top of the majority of my PHP files, because it contains my frequently used functions. I don't understand how its contents could be assigned to a variable after my SQL Query.
The Stored Procedure assigns the value of @FormType and inserts a set of XML data into a temporary table, then outputs the temp table.
Expected output:
Pre-Execute:<br>-_-_-_-<br>

Post-Execute:<br>Termination<br>

{"PAFIndex":504,"TerminationType":"Involuntary","TerminationName":"205,207,210,403","PolicyName":"TEST","OtherText":"TEST"}"

Actual Results:
Pre-Execute:<br>-_-_-_-<br>

Post-Execute:<br>-_-_-_-H:i:s', time());
//*// 8000 characters from Functions.php starting from Position 25 in the file //*//<br>

{"PAFIndex":504,"TerminationType":"Involuntary","TerminationName":"205,207,210,403","PolicyName":"TEST","OtherText":"TEST"}"

Here is the PHP code for my parameters.
        $xmlNewVals = new SimpleXMLElement("<?xml version='1.0'?><data></data>");
        array_to_xml($NewVals, $xmlNewVals);
        
        echo "\nXML Data:<br>{$xmlNewVals->asXML()}<br>\n"; //Confirm XML data accuracy

        unset($FormType2);
        
        $FormType2 = "-_-_-_-"; //Initialize the value.

        $stmtParams[] = array($PAFIndex, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN);
        $stmtParams[] = array($TimeStamp, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN);
        $stmtParams[] = array($xmlNewVals->asXML(), SQLSRV_PARAM_IN, SQLSRV_PHPTYPE_STREAM(SQLSRV_ENC_CHAR), SQLSRV_SQLTYPE_XML);
        $stmtParams[] = array($_SESSION['UserName'], SQLSRV_PARAM_IN);
        $stmtParams[] = array($NewValReason, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN);

        $stmtParams[] = array(&$FormType2, SQLSRV_PARAM_INOUT); //Variable passed by reference.

        $stmt = "{call HR.PAFAlterChecks(?".str_repeat(",?", count($stmtParams)-1).")}";
        
        echo "\nPre-Execute:<br>{$FormType2}<br>\n"; //Correctly contains the initialized value.
        
        $result = ExecSQL($stmt, $hasrows, $stmtParams);
        
        echo "\nPost-Execute:<br>{$FormType2}<br>\n"; //Contains 8000 characters of my Function.php file.

My ExecSQL function contains the following.
function ExecSQL($SQL, &$hasRows = false, $Parameters = array(), $BypassError = false)
{
    global $presql, $postsql, $SQLconnection, $GenericErrorMessage;
    
    unset($Result, $Error);
    $Error = "";
    
    if(empty($Parameters)){ $SQL = $presql.$SQL.$postsql; }

    $Result = sqlsrv_query($SQLconnection, $SQL, $Parameters);

    if(empty($Result)){
        $Errors = sqlsrv_errors();
        foreach($Errors as $i => $err)
        {
            $Error .= $i.": ".$err['message']."  ";
        }
        $Error .= " ({ ".$SQL." }) ";
        
        echo "<br><br>\n";
        print_r($Parameters); //testing only, commented in production
        echo "<br><br>\n";
    }
    else
    {
        do { $hasRows = sqlsrv_has_rows($Result); }
        while($hasRows === false && sqlsrv_next_result($Result));
    }
    
    if(!empty($Error) && empty($BypassError)){
        $bug = debug_backtrace(); 
        $res = Error(substr($bug[0]['file'], strrpos($bug[0]['file'], '\\')+1), $Error, $bug[0]['line']);
        die($GenericErrorMessage."\r\n\t".$Error); 
    }
    
    return $Result;
}

This is my Stored Procedure.
USE [FormsDataTest]
GO

/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [HR].[PAFAlterChecks]    Script Date: 05/09/2024 1:09:58 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE  [HR].[PAFAlterChecks]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @PAFIndex INT,
    @TimeStamp DATETIME = '',
    @NewVal XML,
    @Verifier NVARCHAR(50) = '',
    @NewValReason NVARCHAR(MAX) = '',

    @FormType NVARCHAR(15) OUT

AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    BEGIN TRY
        BEGIN TRANSACTION

        SET @FormType = (SELECT [FormType] FROM HR.PersonnelAction WHERE [index] = @PAFIndex);

        DECLARE @xmlHandle INT

        EXEC sys.sp_xml_preparedocument @xmlHandle OUTPUT, @NewVal
        
        SELECT @PAFIndex AS [PAFIndex], * INTO #NewValues
        FROM OPENXML(@xmlHandle, '/data', 2) 
        WITH ([TerminationType] NVARCHAR(50), 
              [TerminationName] NVARCHAR(MAX), 
              [PolicyName] NVARCHAR(MAX),
              [OtherText] NVARCHAR(MAX)
        )

        EXEC sys.sp_xml_removedocument @xmlHandle

        SELECT * FROM #NewValues --just making sure the xml was input correctly

        DROP TABLE #NewValues

        COMMIT TRANSACTION
        
    END TRY

    BEGIN CATCH
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    END CATCH
END
GO


If I comment out the line "SELECT * FROM #NewValues" in the stored Procedure, I get the Expected Results in the $FormType2 variable. Which confuses me even more, rather than narrow anything down...

I'm going to hazard a guess that some kind of error is happening while enumerating the rows, which is being swallowed, but therefore the OUT parameter is not being set. There are a number of side issues in your SQL code: BEGIN CATCH ROLLBACK is just going to swallow errors, do not do this try-catch at all, instead just put SeT XACT_ABORT ON at the top to ensure rollbacks. Don't use OPENXML t's ancient and unstable, use .nodes() and .value() XML functions instead. In the PHP code, never call die as it won't close connections and cursors properly, instead use try catch finally

.... return $Result; is also very strange as it's a cursor, not a resultset. The use of a temp table is not clear why it's necessary as you could just select the data straight to the client.

Aside... the way the T-SQL is structured when errors do occur then sys.sp_xml_removedocument is likely to not get called and you'll be leaking resources. Consider porting all code away from the SQL 2000-era sys.sp_xml_preparedocument, openxml() and sys.sp_xml_removedocument methods to use the more modern .nodes(), .query() and .value() XML methods instead.

@Charlieface and AlwaysLearning Thank you for the tips on using the new XML functions. I had not seen those before. After some google searches I was able to implement them instead of OPENXML. The reason I was using a Temp Table was because OPENXML couldn't directly modify values in an existing row in another table. I was going to use the temp table for those Update commands. The new functions negate that necessity.
The return $Result does return the resultset, as this function is used for all of the sql queries on my project, and I haven't had an issue.
Thank you both :)
